# Android app can not start for some devices which use MTK6592

Tags: android, mobile

The app runs fun for most of devices.However there are some of devices which use MTK6592 or so can not launch it.The log which I get is like below:

```
04-21 15:50:42.019  25924-25953/com.q.q E/CellLocation﹕ create GsmCellLocation
04-21 15:50:42.035  25924-25924/com.q.q E/linker﹕ load_library(linker.cpp:759): library "libmaliinstr.so" not found
04-21 15:50:42.037  25924-25924/com.qingdaonews.bus E/﹕ appName=com.q.q, acAppName=com.android.cts.openglperf
```

Comment: There is a bunch of stackoverflow questions like this with no answers. Same problem here on a new chinese device with an app running since 2 years ago.